# How to print a character variable number of times PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to print the '#' character a certain number of times where the number of times is `$height2`. I  tried running it, but it only printed 8 0's instead of the #s.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$height = $_REQUEST['height'];
$height2 = "0";
$height3 == $height;

echo "<p>You have requested a height of $height" . "." . "</p>";

while ($height2 < $height - 1)
{
   echo " " * $height2 . "#" * $height;
   $height2 = $height2 + 1;
   $height3 = $height - 1;
}

?>
```

I'm also trying to make each line on separate rows, longest on bottom, then second longest above it etc.

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which the problem is?

Comment: echo "<p>You have requested a height of $height</p>";

Answer (score 0):

try using `char(35)` that is the ASCII code for #